# washed out colours while screen recording on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, colors, nvidia-geforce

I recorded my screen and the colours of video are looking washed out.

I was using OBS so tried using color range settings as suggested by many answers online it did not work

I then tried using simple screen recorder as well as kazam the colors were still dull so its the issue across the os

I found out that I can change color range on my laptop and it might fix the issue but I'm not able to find color settings in NVIDIA X server

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia-driver-460 and the laptop I'm using is ASUS TUF Gaming FX505DT , Ryzen7 3750H, GTX 1650 4GB GDDR5 Graphics